# App shutdown when testing on AVD

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, runtime-error

i'm trying to learn Android and i'm doing a simple exercise involving two buttons and a textview. However when I try to run the app in the emaulator, the app is forced to shutdown.

Below is the code:

```
public class CambiarColorActivity extends Activity 
implements View.OnClickListener {
    Button btnRed;
    Button btnBlue;
    TextView text;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        TextView text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        btnRed=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btnBlue=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);                 
        btnRed.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnBlue.setOnClickListener(this);                   
    }

    public void onClick(View view) {
        changeColor();
    }

    private void changeColor() {
        if(btnRed.isPressed()) {
            text.setBackgroundResource(Color.RED);
        } else {
            text.setBackgroundResource(Color.BLUE);                     
        }
    }
}
```

And these are the errors I found in the log in Eclipse:

```
11-04 11:34:42.377: E/AndroidRuntime(376): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-04 11:34:42.377: E/AndroidRuntime(376): at mi.entrenamiento.OrejanoX.CambiarColorActivity.onCreate(CambiarColorActivity.java:25)
```

Here is my part of my main.xml

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        style="@style/red"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/red"
        android:text="@string/red" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/blue"
        android:text="@string/azul" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Any help will be welcome.

Thanks and Regards, Mauro.

Answer (score 2):

Because the error is

> 11-04 11:34:42.377: E/AndroidRuntime(376): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   11-04 11:34:42.377: E/AndroidRuntime(376): at mi.entrenamiento.OrejanoX.CambiarColorActivity.onCreate(CambiarColorActivity.java:25)

so please see what is on the line 25 of your file.

I guess it is one of the following lines.

```
btnRed.setOnClickListener(this);
btnBlue.setOnClickListener(this);
```

so please check in your main.xml whether you set android:id for the two buttons.

Comment: I have the andoird:id for the teo buttons. Check the original post for new info.

Comment: It seems that you get the error in `changeColor()` because in `onCreate()` you write `TextView text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);`, so text is the local variable in `onCreate()`, not the instance variable. Also notice that `setBackgroundResource()` takes the parameter as resource id, so it will get error here. You should write `text.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED)`

Answer (score 1):

It says you get NullPointerException. I guess that is because on of `btnRed` or `btnBlue` were null. Check and see if you get a valid value from `findViewById`.

Comment: I have added the main.xml to the original post. I do get a null value but I can figure why.

Comment: There are a few reasons for this to happen; Google "findViewById returns null" and I'm sure you will find some.

Answer (score 0):

I found the error it was this line on the main.xml

```
style="@style/red"
```

I deleted and everything was fine.